# Which charset should i use to decode this array of bytes in java?

Tags: java, pdf, utf-8, character-encoding, base64

I am currently working with Soap web services, and more precisely, recovering a file sent within.

**It is working manually** :

In SOAPUi, i do receive this (truncated for readability)

> JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMTIgMCBvY [...]
>   dL0luZm8gMTggMCBSL1NpemUgMTk+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKNjk5OQolJUVPRgo=

I can paste this string within notepad++ and after clicking on MIME Tools > base 64 Decode, it become a proper PDF File as follows ( Truncated , just header is shown)

> %PDF-1.4 %xE2xE3xCFxD3LF 12 0 obj <>stream

PDF File can be thus read without any problem.

**Problem** is now to recover this data using java.
I am receiving an array of byte (acopier variable in example below) and using the following code to store into a file.
I tried a couple of the numerous examples found on the net without any success.

Also tried to use UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 amongst others.

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
    try{
    String filePath="c:\\temp\\";
    filePath = filePath.concat("test.pdf");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath,false);
    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos,"UTF-8");
    osw.write("\uFEFF");
    osw.write(new String(acopier));
    osw.close();
    System.out.println("Success");
    fos.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    osw.close();
    }
```

Unfortunately, file can't be seen as a pdf file,

> %PDF-1.4 %âãÏÓ 12 0 obj <>stream

When i tried to check what's within the array of bytes, console is showing me this : (truncated)

> % P D F
>   - 1 . 4
>
> % ? ? ? ?
>
> 1 2   0

I presume that windows or notepad++ or soapui is doing something in the background to guess what charset to use but i don't know with certitude which way to go.

Can please someone clarify me how to do it from scratch in java (meaning from the original array of bytes)?

Regards,

Pierre

Comment: If you debug the execution, what do you get as a Base64 String? Is it just the same you tried decoding in Notepad++? If so, try decoding it again after getting the bytes. Next step, you could check which is the encoding Notepad++ is using!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Get the original (Base64) string data
2. Use your preferred Base64 decoder to turn it into bytes (plenty of them for Java)
3. Write bytes to file. As **bytes**, not as character data (i.e. no `Writer` class).

Since in your example you're trying to write binary data as character data (and using the `String` constructor), I assume you're quite new to Java?

Your mistake was converting base64 to binary data in notepad, then saving the result thinking that it would be valid binary data (which it almost most definitely isn't, and even if it did work, that's not the road you want to ).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Kayaman. You were right about mistakes i've made and my java skills to be improved :)

Comment: No problem. Different encodings and formats can be confusing when you haven't come across them before. Charset encodings especially.